# Readable unit testing of a yielded sequence?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, yield, sequences

Let's suppose I have some method that returns a `IEnumerable<int>` object. This methods make use of `yield return` keyword to produce a infinite sequence. Example of the Fibonacci algorithm :

```
public static IEnumerable<long> Fibonacci()
{
    long x = 0L;
    long y = 1L;
    long z;
    yield return x;
    yield return y;
    while (true)
    {
        z = x + y;
        yield return z;
        y = x;
        x = z;
    }
}
```

How can I properly create unit test for such sequence ? By proper I also mean readable.

I can write unit tests like this :

```
[TestMethod]
public void FibonacciTest()
{
    var actual = MyClass.Fibonacci();

    var @enum = actual.GetEnumerator();

    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 0);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 1);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 2);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 3);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
    Assert.AreEqual(@enum.Current), 5);
    Assert.IsTrue(@enum.MoveNext();
}
```

This test works, but I don't think it is readable. What are general (Fibonacci alogrithm was only a example) guidelines for writing unit tests for sequences ?

PS: I'm using Visual Studio OOB Test suite + Pex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] {0,1,1,2,3,5}, MyClass.Fibonacci().Take(6).ToList());
```

Comment: Never saw `CollectionAssert` before :) This should simplify most of sequence unit test! thx

Comment: @SteveB I didn't down vote, but I think the reason as that the CollectionAssert takes an ICollection (in MSTest). Whereas Take(n) will return an IEnumerable<T>, so that won't actually compile.

Comment: @RichK: A simple `.ToList()` would have solve the problem. The downvoter should have notify Matt instead of downvote.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FibonacciFirstSixTest()
{
    var actual = MyClass.Fibonacci();
    int[] expected = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };

    Assert.IsTrue(actual.Take(6).SequenceEqual(expected));
}
```

By the way, I would point out that you don't *really* have an infinite sequence there since there are only so many members of the Fibonacci series that can fit in `long` (or any fixed-size data-type for that matter). You might as well test all 92 of them.

Comment: As I said, Fibonacci was only an example. I have the same method with BigInteger, or other methods like `IEnumerable<T[]> GetPermutations(T[] source)` that produces a large number of items if not an infinite. Anyways, thanks for the answer.