# Correction into the right direction C#

Tags: c#, fibonacci

So I tried to generate the fibonacci algorithm in C# however, I everytime I run this code I am getting an error that states:

> The type or namespace name `IList' could not be found. Are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am lost..where am I going wrong? Thank you...

```
public IList<int> GenerateFibonacci(int toIndex)
{
     IList<int> sequence;
     sequence.Add(0);
     sequence.Add(1);

     for (int i=0; i<toIndex; i++)
     {
         sequence.Add(sequence[i], sequence[i+1]);
     }

     return sequence;
}
```

Comment: You forget `c#-2.0` tag.

Comment: add reference to `System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: BTW, you do not initialize `sequence`.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line: sequence.Add(sequence[i], sequence[i+1]);

Comment: I'd advise **against** returning an Interface (e.g. `IList`), unless your method actually returns different types of objects that all implement that interface.

Comment: I prefer using the Linq styled enumerator: [`public static IEnumerable<long> Fibonacci()
{
    long x = 0L;
    long y = 1L;
    long z;
    yield return x;
    yield return y;
    while (true)
    {
        z = x + y;
        yield return z;
        y = x;
        x = z;
    }
}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263479/readable-unit-testing-of-a-yielded-sequence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you miss `System.Collections.Generic`, here is a correct version of your program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  public class Program
  {
    public IList<int> GenerateFibonacci(int toIndex)
    {

      IList<int> sequence = new List<int>();

      sequence.Add(0);

      sequence.Add(1);

      for (int i = 0; i < toIndex; i++)
      {

        sequence.Add(sequence[i]+ sequence[i + 1]);

      }

      return sequence;

    }

    static void Main()
    {
      var s = GenerateFibonacci(10);     
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Houssem, i think you should post your eMail so that OP can ask his/her further homeworks directly to you ... :)

Answer (score 1):

add using System.Collections.Generic and try it again

Comment: You may also hover your mouse over the red underlined `IList`, then click on the little box that appears or click on the word `IList` and press Ctrl + . (dot). A menu will appear and suggest possible ways to solve the problem. In this case, either by replacing `IList` with `System.Collections.Generic.IList` or by adding a `using System.Collections.Generic;`.